# Don't see Super User account in my accounts tab

Tags: support, status-completed, superuser, multiple-accounts

One of my answers was migrated from SO to Super User. My new account was created automatically, I just logged in (confirmed the OpenID, etc.). But when I go to the "accounts" tab in my user page (here on SO but also on Super User!), I don't see my Super User account there!
Where's the problem?

I also see 3 suspicious buttons below:

- Copy XXX profile to all StackExchange accounts *(XXX depends on site. I think this is not related to my problem)*
- Clear all Stack Exchange account associations *(I suppose I dont want to do this!!)*
- Copy XXX login credentials to all .... *(I also think this is not related)*

Please give me advice what should I do to see my Super User account in the "accounts" tab.

Comment: Looks fine to me from the [Super User side](http://superuser.com/users/93604/tomas-telensky?tab=accounts)... You have to give it a few minutes to sync your account associations.

Comment: @cody it displays "accounts are syncing, check back in {x} minutes" when you disassociate and reassociate now. X starts at 15.

Comment: @Cody Gray: nope, I see the superuser account neither [in the Super User site accounts tab](http://superuser.com/users/93604/tomas-telensky?tab=accounts) nor in the [SO site accounts tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/684229/tomas-telensky?tab=accounts). And it's much more than 15 minutes... I think like 2 hours at least.

Comment: Now I have the very same problem with "Game development" StackExchange site for more than 3 days.

Comment: @tomas Kevin will look at this tomorrow, we can repro

Comment: @Jeff, it is very strange that some sites appear there immediatelly after creating account there, some other (like game dev or english language) won't appear for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow works now already.